# Enable the default image viewer on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, lightbox, tumblr

How would you go about disabling a default function which enlarges an image? I am creating a Theme for my Tumblr blog and I want to make it so that when a user clicks on the image they are redirected to the link of the actual post rather than seeing an enlarged image.

For a greater understanding of what I am talking about click on an image on the following Tumblog page:

http://cyrillkuhlmann.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent a function from firing all you have to do is the following with JQuery

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("img").click(function (){
    return false;
    // This will prevent the light box from firing when you click the image
    });
});
```

Comment: Works! But it blocks the link completely… Can I let it block to show the "single" image? I just want to let it show the single post (with caption and so on)…

Comment: $("img").click(function (){
     event.preventDefault();
     var UR = $(this).parents("article").data("post-id");
     var UR = UR.replace(/_/,"/");
     var pge = window.location.href;
     window.location.assign( pge + UR);
});

Comment: …one last question, when I click on the image again… on the "single post page" … it says 404 file not found… is it possible to relink to the same page? so that the user has to use the browser or click the header to come back to the overview?

Comment: I see you've changed the theme of your page slightly, do you still need further instruction or are you fine? :)